# Show/Hide ul li onclick jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to show/hide my submenus when a `<a href="#"></a>` is clicked.
Here is a code example :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
    <li class="submenu">
        <a href="#">Test 2</a>
        <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
            <li class="submenu_2">
                <a href="#">Test 3</a>
                <ul class="ul_submenu_2">
                    <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$( 'li.submenu a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("ul.ul_submenu").css("display","block");
}, function() {
    $("ul.ul_submenu").css("display","none");
});
```

You can find a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sy757gvj/).

I need to allow click on a tag when there are children elements, and modify the display of li. But I need to cancel the page reload when user clicks on a tag like this : `<a href="#"></a>`

Comment: you need this? https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6177/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do,

```
$('li a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest("li").find("[class^='ul_submenu']").slideToggle();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6177/)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just return `false` in the click callback. And `click()` only has one callback function, not two. What was your plan?

And you dont need to use `css()`, just use `show()`.

```
$(function() {
    $('li.submenu a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("ul.ul_submenu").show()
        return false;
    });
});
```

And you should make it more dynamically. Somhow like this, for all menu entries. I've edited your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sy757gvj/5/

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
  <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Test 2</a>
    <ul class="ul_submenu">
      <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
      <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Test 3</a>
        <ul class="ul_submenu">
          <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

-

```
$(function() {
    $('li.submenu a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 1):

This code will open "Test2" submenu:

```js
$('li.submenu a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().children("ul.ul_submenu").show();
});
```

```css
.ul_submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
  <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Test 2</a>
    <ul class="ul_submenu">
      <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
      <li class="submenu_2"><a href="#">Test 3</a>
        <ul class="ul_submenu_2">
          <li><a href="www.example.com">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggle` function for the same.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.submenu a[href="#"]').click(function(){
        $("ul.ul_submenu").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your jquery to this:

`$('li.submenu').on('click','a[href="#"]',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("ul.ul_submenu").toggle();
})`

and it seems to work. 
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y0p13dt7/1/