# Hide one <li> when clicking another <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m using `toggle` to show `<li>` and hide other `<li>`.

```js
$('.hassub').click(function() {
  $(this).find('ul.hassub1').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="mainLi active open"><a href="#" class="pageNav"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>Demo Grp</a>
  <ul style="height:auto;">
    <li class="mainLi hassub"><a href="#" class="pageNav"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Demo SUb Grp2</a>
      <ul class="hassub1" style="margin-top: 1%; display: none;">
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-link fa-cogs"></i>AE_TAT</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-link fa-cogs"></i>Agent_Analysis</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mainLi hassub"><a href="#" class="pageNav"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Demo Sub Grp</a>
      <ul class="hassub1" style="margin-top: 1%; display: block;">
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-link fa-cogs"></i>AE_CCL_TAT</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-link fa-cogs"></i>Customer_Profile_Analysis</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

need to close li if second time clicks on different li

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: Your code looks good and it works! Just a typo may be.

Comment: @ArupRakshit code working fine but on first click opens and others or closing and again if i click second li its not opening , on second click its opening

Comment: @Jennifer Can you please add the exact JS you have there and html ?

Comment: `$('ul.hassub1').click(function(){
$(this).find('hassub').toggle();                

}` append this to your code

Comment: if($('ul li li:has(ul)').find('hassub1')){
   
   $('.hassub1').css({'display':'none'});
  
   }                                       $('.hassub').click(function(){ $(this).find('ul.hassub').toggle();}

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar That is not syntactially correct. OP has logical issue not syntactical.

Comment: @Jennifer Edit your original question.

Comment: @Jennifer can you elaborate more ? edit question , dont comment please

Comment: also @Jennifer we need your HTML to tests

Comment: @ArupRakshit Thats is my code

Comment: can someone reopen the question pls

Comment: try this code `$(this).parent().find('ul.hassub1').toggle();`

Comment: @NaveenSingh if i go with your code both li are opening of first li

Comment: @Jennifer use `currentSelected = undefined;

$('.hassub').click(function() {
  if(currentSelected) {currentSelected.find('ul.hassub1').toggle();}
  $(this).find('ul.hassub1').toggle();
  currentSelected = $(this);
});`
the default display must be set to none for all `ul.hassub1` by default

Comment: @Jennifer here's a JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/b8nky6zp/

Comment: ok sorry I created it according to one ul opened try with this : 
`  $(this).siblings().find('.hassub1').hide();
  $(this).find('ul.hassub1').toggle();`

Comment: @Xufox can you reopen please, now that we have a full question, we can help the OP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/Hide ul li onclick jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970446/show-hide-ul-li-onclick-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code on your click function :

```
$(this).siblings().find('.hassub1').hide(); 
$(this).find('ul.hassub1').toggle();
```